# during jasper report generation date value is not getting set sometimes

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports, weblogic, simpledateformat

I am passing date as key in parameter and value as dateFormate.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

But some times it is getting set to current date but sometimes it set to null.

The only difference is that one application is running in Linux with weblogic server and another one is in Windows tomcat server.

Can somebody let me know what might be the reason.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
parameters.put(ReportConstants.JR_PARAM_DATE, dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

parameters value i am passing to jasper template.

Note: Templates are same in both the environment.

Comment: That sounds weird alright. You may want to see it the `java.time` classes behave better: `DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");` and then `parameters.put(ReportConstants.JR_PARAM_DATE, dateFormat.format(LocalDate.now()));`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved by changing the Jasper report variable ReportConstants.JR_PARAM_DATE focus to the screen. it was overflowing from the report and not in focus of screen.

It was not an issue in Tomcat server but it was only with WebLogic server. 
I am not sure for the reason. but it got resolved by this. I think weblogic has some other restrict specification for the Jasper report and it was failing in that.